# Bootstrap grid rows with no top or bottom padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having an issue getting my grid rows to be "tight" against the adjacent rows, with no vertical space between them. As of now, it is placing something like 20px between every row.

```
    .container {width: 640px;}

    .row {width: 640px; spacing: 0px; padding: 0px;}

    .grid{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 640px;
    }

    .thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

    .col-xs-3{
    width: 210px;padding: 2px;}
```

Comment: Did you check the margins?

Comment: you have put 2px of padding on your cols top and bottom. I wouldn't recommend missing with the Bootstrap grid rows and cols - you are making a responsive framework unresponsive....

Comment: The 2px padding on the col-xs-3 is mainly for the horizontal spacing between the rows. There still seems to be a 20px vertical margin between rows with or without the 2px

Comment: Also, I'm fairly new to this! Thank you all for your help so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things.

1) This line of CSS
   `.row {width: 640px; spacing: 0px; padding: 0px;}`
   *spacing* is not a CSS attribute

2) This has to deal with [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

3) How to override

```
.no-spacing {
    margin: 0; padding:0;
}
```

Add this to your CSS file and link it *after* bootstrap. Then add the class to the elements you want not to use bootstrap's spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You write in your question about the *vertical* spacing so I think that you are addressing the gap *between* the columns and not *below* the rows. Bootstrap is adding a 15px right and left padding to each column.

You can overwrite this in your custom CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.col-xs-3 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

But you must do this for each col-* class then.

And as written in the first answer there is no "spacing" CSS rule.

Comment: Thank you... I am actually addressing the space below the rows, not the space between the columns

Comment: However Bootstrap does not define spacing there by default.